# I not able to search decimal integer with using find count

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakephp 1.3 and I am not able to search decimal integer by using find count. If I am using integer such as 2 and it was working fine, but if I use integer such as 1.01 and find count is not working.

```
$checkprice= $this->Bid->find('count',array('conditions' => array('Bid.auction_id' => $id,'Bid.price' =>$cprice)));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Count how many there are with this specific price?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a decimal integer. It is either an integer or a decimal.

> if I use integer such as 1.01

This is a decimal. The count will only work for integers. Whole numbers, eg 0, 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: sorry...at model,i use numeric